# Custom Error Handling in Forms (Laravel 5)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For the fields of a form, I can use this in my blade and for the fields of the form, it handles errors nicely in the form.

```
 @if($errors->any())
       <div class="alert alert-error">
       <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            {!! implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</li>')) !!}
      </div>
 @endif
```

and `public function rules()`

However, I want to use the same concept for my custom errors in the form, that I believe I can not achieve with `rules()`.

In my Controller, I have:

```
if ($fileExtension != 'pdf')
   {
        // needs proper handling
   }
```

How can I edit `// needs proper handling` part so that I can use it with the same blade concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mime type rule you can use:

```
'yourFile' => 'mimes:pdf'
```

If your run more than just a validation you can use this longer method:

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);

$validator->after(function($validator) {
    if ($fileExtension != 'pdf') {
        #here is place for more stuff...
        $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how about if I have multiple checks like the if condition that I can't use with `mimes`. Like your second validation code, can I insert more if statements under there? Maybe `file size` or `if file exists`? Thanks

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-size will give you more information. You can check everything and if you are not satisfied with it you add an error with `$validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');`

Comment: I got confused about this longer method. Is there a way to put all of the validations (both custom `if's` and laravel's `size`,`required`, etc) in `rules` (Request) ? Or do I need to put some in the Controller and others in Request? I am trying to ask if there is a way to _put custom multiple error handlings in validation_.

Comment: In the Request file you can only pass things like 'yourFile' => 'mimes:pdf'`. If this doesn't work for everything you can check the rest in your controller.